# Authentication failing for Modulr API - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, hmacsha1

The API docs are [here](https://modulr.readme.io/docs/authentication)

The only code example is in Java, [here](https://github.com/Modulr-finance/modulr-hmac/blob/master/samples/java/src/test/java/com/modulr/api/ModulrApiAuthTest.java)

Every time I try to authenticate I get:

```
{
    "error": "Authorization field missing, malformed or invalid"
}
```

I have been through the auth docs many times over and still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import secrets
import codecs

from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

import urllib.parse

key     = '<API_KEY>'
secret  = '<API_SECRET>'

# Getting current time
now = datetime.now()
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())

# Formats time into this format --> Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:36:07 GMT
formated_time = format_date_time(stamp)

# Generates a secure random string for the nonce
nonce = secrets.token_urlsafe(30)

# Combines date and nonce into a single string that will be signed
signature_string = 'date' + ':' + formated_time + '\n' + 'x-mod-nonce' + ':' + nonce

# Expected output example --> date: Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:36:07 GMT\nx-mod-nonce: 28154b2-9c62b93cc22a-24c9e2-5536d7d

# Encodes secret and message into a format that can be signed
secret = bytes(secret, encoding='utf-8')
message = bytes(signature_string,encoding='utf-8')

# Signing process
digester = hmac.new(secret, message, hashlib.sha1)

# Converts to hex
hex_code = digester.hexdigest()

# Decodes the signed string in hex into base64
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex_code, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()

# Encodes the string so it is safe for URL
url_safe_code = urllib.parse.quote(b64,safe='')

# Adds the key and signed response
authorization = f'Signature keyId="{key}",algorithm="hmac-sha1",headers="date x-mod-nonce",signature="{url_safe_code}"'

account_id = 'A120BU48'

url = f'https://api-sandbox.modulrfinance.com/api-sandbox/accounts/{account_id}'

headers = {
    'Authorization': authorization, # Authorisation header
    'Date' : formated_time,         # Date header
    'x-mod-nonce': nonce,           # Addes nonce
    'accept': 'application/json',
    }

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am not sure where the process is going wrong, as far as I know, the signature is being signed correctly as I added in the test data from the authentication example and I get the expected string.

If you want to try with real API keys, register for access [here](https://secure-sandbox.modulrfinance.com/#/sandbox/onboarding)

The docs for the API endpoint I am trying to call is [here](https://modulr.readme.io/reference#getaccountusingget-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you linked has a space between the colon and the values.

`signature_string = 'date' + ':' + formated_time + '\n' + 'x-mod-nonce' + ':' + nonce`

should be:
`signature_string = 'date' + ': ' + formated_time + '\n' + 'x-mod-nonce' + ': ' + nonce`

or (simpler):
`signature_string = 'date: ' + formated_time + '\n' + 'x-mod-nonce: ' + nonce`

**Update**
I registered to see what is going on. I also ran your code on the example given in the documentation and saw that the signature is not entirely correct.
In addition to the change I suggested above, a further change was necessary.

After changing the line

```
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex_code, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()
```

to

```
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex_code, 'hex'), 'base64').decode().strip()
```

the signature of the example matched.

After this I was able to connect to the API with my own keys.

Here is the complete working code:

```
import codecs
import hashlib
import hmac
import secrets
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time

import requests

key = '<key>'
secret = '<secret>'
account_id = '<account id>'
url = f'https://api-sandbox.modulrfinance.com/api-sandbox/accounts/{account_id}'

# Getting current time
now = datetime.now()
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())

# Formats time into this format --> Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:36:07 GMT
formatted_time = format_date_time(stamp)

# Generates a secure random string for the nonce
nonce = secrets.token_urlsafe(30)

# Combines date and nonce into a single string that will be signed
signature_string = 'date' + ': ' + formatted_time + '\n' + 'x-mod-nonce' + ': ' + nonce

# Encodes secret and message into a format that can be signed
secret = bytes(secret, encoding='utf-8')
message = bytes(signature_string, encoding='utf-8')

# Signing process
digester = hmac.new(secret, message, hashlib.sha1)

# Converts to hex
hex_code = digester.hexdigest()

# Decodes the signed string in hex into base64
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex_code, 'hex'), 'base64').decode().strip()

# Encodes the string so it is safe for URL
url_safe_code = urllib.parse.quote(b64, safe='')

# Adds the key and signed response
authorization = f'Signature keyId="{key}",algorithm="hmac-sha1",headers="date x-mod-nonce",signature="{url_safe_code}"'

headers = {
    'Authorization': authorization,  # Authorisation header
    'Date': formatted_time,  # Date header
    'x-mod-nonce': nonce,  # Adds nonce
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, tried it,but this seems to have no effect. If you want to register for sandbox access is pretty easy, just go here - https://secure-sandbox.modulrfinance.com/#/sandbox/onboarding

Comment: Ah, sad to hear. Have you checked the value of the `authorization` variable? Does it look OK? (And of course, is your API KEY and SECRET KEY correct?)

Comment: I'd suggest to use the values for keys and nonce from their example, see which part is not matching, and work on fixing those

Comment: @Kareem please see my update with the working code.

Comment: @vekerdyb thanks for helping Kareem resolve the issue. I work for Modulr ( the guys behind the API) . Do either of you mind if I put this code snippet as an example on our github?

Comment: @RiteshTendulkar not at all, go for it!